# Mapping table over multiple values sql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

At first i had 2 table:

Room is a table which store the room and their type.
Reservation is a table where users make their booking.

```
Room (roomnumber, roomtype, price)

Reservation (reservationid,roomnumber, checkin, checkout)
```

`reservationid` can have multiple values of `roomnumber(for e.g, 100,101,102,..)` and as I cannot input multiple values in a single column in sql, I have decided to make to table like that:

```
Room (roomnumber, roomtype, price)

Reservation (reservationid, checkin, checkout)

RoomReserve( reservation_id, room_id)
```

In RoomReserve, for each reservationid, I can input multiple values for room_id.

For e.g,

```
reservationid     roomid
           5                 100  
           5                 102
           5                 103
```

But the problem is if i input another `reservationid(for e.g '6')` in 
  RoomReserve, then i cannot re enter the the roomid which was used previously(for e.g '100','102','103').

please tell me if the table i have created for roomreserve is good, if yes, what column must i put as primary key or foreign key.

I am using these tables in php.
Thanks.

Comment: The question quite tend to code review (so it's better to post the question here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and is primarily opinion based

Comment: okk raymond i will try to post it there.